# How to access updated Values from Async Call in Angular Unit Test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a Component method Like this :

```
component { 
let a = 1;

     parentFunc(){
        const res = fromEvent(reader,'loadend').pipe()
        .subscribe(()=>{
             this.a =5;
         });
       }
}
```

Code inside it of test case :

```
it("test spec", function() {
    component.parentFunc();

    expect(component.a).toBe(5);
  });
```

I am writing a Unit Test for this and when I call the parentFunc it prints the updated value in the console.

But when I try to access it Unit test like component.a It always returns the old value.

What is the best way to verify this value?

Comment: Can you share the code regarding the unit test

Comment: @uiTeam324 check now if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **a** is not a property of **component A**. So, when you update **a**'s value, you always get old value.

You should try doing following,

```
component A { 
 a = 1;

     parentFunc(){
        fromEvent(reader,'loadend').pipe()
        .subscribe(()=>{
             this.a =5;
         });
       }
}
```

Now if you check `component.a` it should have `5` value.

Comment: Hey, Sorry but the variable name was typo. Can you check the updated question and see what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
  it('test spec', () => {
     spyOn(component, 'fromEvent').and.returnValue(of({}));
    component.parentFunc();
    expect(component.a).toEqual(5);
});
```

Also Use `this.a =5;` inside your function.

Comment: parentFunc does not return Observable . What happens when there are multiple variables being updated as you have assumed value to contain  updated value

Comment: Updated my answer , check